# Forge Autodesk.Viewing.ZoomWindow extension is not working

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

The extension used to work when it is simply added to `GuiViewer3D` as an extension option, such as :

```
options = {extension:['Autodesk.Viewing.ZoomWindow']};
viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(htmlDiv,options);
```

I checked it with `EXTENSION_LOADED_EVENT` eventListener

[image]

Actually it is loaded. But somehow on toolbar it only shows default(dolly) option.

What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently looks like there's been a regression with this extension in one of the recent upgrades and can confirm to be getting the below error which must have prevented the plugin from loading:

```
document not ready yet, trying again in 500 milliseconds...
```

As a workaround delay the loading of the extension till when the document is fully ready - see live demo [here](https://jsbin.com/zukucit/edit?js)

```
NOP_VIEWER.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.MODEL_ROOT_LOADED_EVENT,()=>{

NOP_VIEWER.loadExtension('Autodesk.Viewing.ZoomWindow')

})
```

[image]